# Socket.io express - Not emiting when ~70+ clients

Tags: nginx, socket.io, server, cloudflare, web-traffic

I'm running a virtual linux server with socket.io express installed and using nginx to host the site. Everything works fine until I have ~70+ clients connected, which causes some clients to not receive the emit command, thus making the site not update for them. (They will get some emits while ignoring others, so they're not timing out)

Could it be my ddos protection (cloudflare) or my server which isn't good enough to handle the traffic?

Comment: I would suspect server before ddos protection, since this is outgoing traffic, not incoming. Look at your network throughput and I/O throughput, are they hitting a max and not going any higher? This would help with finding the bottleneck.

Comment: @Kevin B Looking at the network usage graph supplied by my host, there don't seem to be any bottlenecks. [graph](https://gyazo.com/cfaca41c3a9663f06c39c8a16a544527) There are no graphs representing I/O throughput, but I made a ticket with my provider, and they assured me no bottlenecking was happening there either.

Comment: http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/ might be helpful.

Comment: you don't seem to be getting anywhere close to any bottlenecks that i can think of based on information in question. No resource issues? (cpu/memory?)

Comment: @Kevin B According to the graphs my host provides I've only ever utilized 5% of my cpu maximum and 1.5gb out of 3gb of ram. [CPU](https://gyazo.com/db2f798d73a1d108ee9b48dbd2cf3b8e) [RAM](https://gyazo.com/9232c6e37763c78ba9d241e3b6b594f9)